# Oracle: Casting timestamp as date and comparing result

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, timestamp, date

I don‘t really understand what `cast(timestamp as date)` is doing. I am on Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0.

```
select cast(to_timestamp('20190516 08:00:00', 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS') as date) from dual
```

Displays the date 20190516 (without time) in the date format I have in my session.

```
select to_timestamp('20190516 08:00:00', 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

Shows the date with time in my session format. So far everything as I expected.

So casting seems to remove the time part. Now I want to compare the result of the cast with a date which works in SQL Server but not Oracle.

```
select case when cast(to_timestamp('20190516 08:00:00', 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS') as date) = to_date('20190516', 'yyyymmdd') then 1 else 0 end as match from dual; -- 0 = not matched
select case when trunc(to_timestamp('20190516 08:00:00', 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS')) = to_date('20190516', 'yyyymmdd') then 1 else 0 end as match from dual; -- 1 = matched
```

What exacty is returned by `cast(to_timestamp('20190516 08:00:00', 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS') as date)` when it does not seem to be just the date as indicated by the first select? Why can‘t I compare the result?

As shown I luckily have another solution with `trunc()`. I would like to know why comparing does not work  and if there is a possiblity to get the compare to work with `cast`. I am porting a view from SQL Server to Oracle and would like to keep as much as possible the same and it is done with `cast` in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting to a `DATE` datatype from a `TIMESTAMP` only removes the fractional seconds, therefore your direct `to_date('20190516', 'yyyymmdd')` comparison is rightly failing. It's just a display issue that has confused you.

Definition of the Oracle `DATE` datatype (from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm)):

> Valid date range from January 1, 4712 BC to December 31, 9999 AD. The
>   default format is determined explicitly by the NLS_DATE_FORMAT
>   parameter or implicitly by the NLS_TERRITORY parameter. The size is
>   fixed at 7 bytes. This datatype contains the datetime fields YEAR,
>   MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. It does not have fractional
>   seconds or a time zone.

[This DB Fiddle demonstrates](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=611ad13c0d557b0d87fa227b8a41859e).

These queries probably demonstrate best:

```
-- cast to date, and format with TO_CHAR to show that the time element still exists
select  TO_CHAR(
               cast(to_timestamp('20190516 08:00:00', 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS') as date)
                ,'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS') from dual; 

-- demonstrate that the fractional element gets removed 
select cast(
         cast(to_timestamp('20190516 08:00:00.123', 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS.FF')
              as date) 
       as timestamp) from dual;
```